# How I can Create many answer

Tags: javascript, html, css

hello i'm work for question system i want to add many answers in a one question in a one value

html

```
<input id="an" placeholder="test" type="text"/><a id="wo" style="display:none;">done test</a><button id="bt">Submit</button>
```

javascript

```
const an = document.getElementById("an");
const bt = document.getElementById("bt");

bt.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (an.value.toLowerCase() === "test") { // I want create many value in here.
    bt.style.display = "none";
    an.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("wo").style.display = "initial";

  } else {
    bt.innerText = "Wrong!"
    bt.style.background = "red";
  }
});
```

Comment: Not related, but change `></input>` to `/>`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this answer is what you are looking for:

You can make an array with your answers, and then check to see if the given answer is inside the array.

```
const array = ['test', 'test2', 'test3'];

if (array.includes(an.value.toLowerCase() ) )
  ...
```

Something else, you are missing a semicolon in your else { ... }.
`bt.innerText = "Wrong!";`